# Mobile Chrome scrollTop/animate doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem with the mobile version of Chrome.
I want to scroll to a certain position in my html document after loading. I tried to simply use a anchor (#someId) at the end of the url which works fine in FF and desktop version of Chrome. But not on the mobile version.

To work around this I added a scrolTop with a little bit of delay like so:

```
var aTag = $("a[href='#someId']");
setTimeout(function() {
    $('html,body').scrollTop( aTag.offset().top);
}, 250)
```

I'm using jQuery version 1.12.1

Again, it works everywhere except in the mobile version of Chrome - funny enough when I talk about the mobile version I just have to use the developer tools and tell them to display the page as it would be on the phone.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: this is pretty old version of jQuery ... might be some unresolved issue from the past. Try to upgrade to the latest one.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't do that.
But I tried to use plain Javascript with the scrollTo function as well and it didn't work

Comment: and does using `$('html,body').scrollTop(0);` work?

Comment: also check that if you're not disabling scroll by CSS media query for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I made it work with `aTag.get(0).scrollIntoView()` :-)